# Endnote reset style

Tags: microsoft-word, endnote

I accidentally reset the style of my manuscript completely (in word). The accidental part is that I didn't intend the superscript style of the references to become 'normal' text.

How to select all Endnote references and make them highlighted again?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the Endnote is removing? Would you mind to share a screenshot about the current Endnotes?

Comment: No, the references are still there. It's just instead of superscript (NJEM style), the superscripted numbers are now unformatted text, and changingin the style back and forth does not re-format any reference numbers in the text